# How to create Spinner Action Item in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyone know how to create the submenu with radio buttons like in the screenshot?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a submenu with checkable radio buttons you should use something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/red"
              android:title="@string/red" />
        <item android:id="@+id/blue"
              android:title="@string/blue" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And then in the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.red:
            return true;
        case R.id.blue:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the example might work, the solution has some side effects. 1. The group items are put into the overflow menu together with other overflow items. 2. Because they are put into overflow menu, they are the last item. 3. If you try to add two groups, they are joined together in the overflow menu. 4. On phones with hw menu button, the items are created as standard menu items displayed with the menu button.